# How can I forward the client's IP Address to Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-places-api

I am calling Google Places Autocomplete API from a web server, so when the client code is unable to capture latitude/longitude from the browser, location biasing will always be based on my server's IP address by default. I am trying to find a way to pass to Google the client's IP address instead of it using mine. I have captured the client IP on my server API, but there doesn't seem to be any way to forward that in an Autocomplete request.

From the documentation, Google states:

> Note: If you do not supply the location and radius, the API will
>   attempt to detect the user's location from their IP address, and will
>   bias the results to that location.

I've attempted to add different headers to the Autocomplete Request, but they are all ignored and still bias results on my server IP. Maybe I haven't found the correct header.

```
//pseudo C#
headers.Add("X-ProxyUser-Ip", "172.217.5.228");
headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", "172.217.5.228");
```

Is there a proper way to forward a client IP from my server to Google API?

src: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#location_biasing

Comment: Why not request the API from javascript/jquery? Then it has the user's ip address. Or is that not possible?

Comment: It is not possible in my situation because there is a requirement to not expose the API Key.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Google Places server-side API does not support IP address as a parameter for location biasing. So you have two options.

1. Use client-side API (You have mentioned this is not feasible)
2. Call a reverse geolocation API to get the country code of an IP.
   Then pass this country code to Google places API via components parameter.

**example for Ipfind service**

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
  string ip_address = "10.23.45.154";
  string URL = "https://api.ipfind.com/?ip=" + ip_address;

  var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
  // extract ISO country code here and call Google Places API
}
```

> **components** — A grouping of places to which you would like to restrict
>   your results. Currently, you can use components to filter by up to 5
>   countries. Countries must be passed as a two character, ISO 3166-1
>   Alpha-2 compatible country code. For example: components=country:fr
>   would restrict your results to places within France. Multiple
>   countries must be passed as multiple country:XX filters, with the pipe
>   character (|) as a separator. For example:
>   components=country:us|country:pr|country:vi|country:gu|country:mp
>   would restrict your results to places within the United States and its
>   unincorporated organized territories.

Comment: Ugh. Google API developers create such annoying to use APIs. They literally have a feature for IP biasing in use, yet they don't allow you to pass user IPs to the API as a parameter. An obvious miss.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you've already looked through official Google documentation and [restricting](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) a key to your owned domain does not suit you.

I guess then you can try calling a 3rd party API to roughly bias client IP to location and the use it for you Google autocomplete.

Comment: Yes, I am already restricting by domain. They still require it to be hidden regardless.

Comment: Well, then I guess you might try to pre-bias your client based on their IP before calling Google. There are quite a few services online that claim to do that. I never used these, so I'm not comfortable putting a recommendation forward.